# input character inside a while loop with validation

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter the operator (+ - X /): ");
operator = input.next();
char c=operator.charAt(0);
while (c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '*' && c != '/'){
    System.out.println("Operator doesn't match. Try again.");
    System.out.print("Enter the operator (+ - X /): ");
    input.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Here, I want an input character value from keyboard which will be only symbols just (+ - * /) inside a `while` loop. if the sign is not match the while loop will be running.

Here, the `while` loop is working but the character is not checked. So, while loop continuously works with-

```
System.out.println("Operator doesn't match. Try again.");
System.out.print("Enter the operator (+ - X /): ");
```

Comment: change 'input.next().charAt(0);' line inside the while loop to 'c=input.next().charAt(0);' it slove your issue. currently c value not change inside while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line of your while loop, you are retrieving an user input, but not storing it anywhere. You should do like that:

```
c = input.next().charAt(0);
```

If you want to do something fancy, you could also try using the [do-while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), like below:

```
char c;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a operator (+ - * /):");
    c = input.next().charAt(0);
} while(c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '*' && c != '/');
```

Comment: That's true! Thanks for pointing it out, I already corrected it. I must be too tired, time to go to bed hahah